# Add Voice Response to an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, speech

This is for a mobile only site:

I want to have a button on my page, when pressed the user can speak into their phone and when they finish talking a random mp3 file is triggered. Is this possible in JQuery?

Comment: Yes, but not many browsers support it (http://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition). You can read more here: http://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/

Answer (score 1):

This page demonstrates how you can do it.

http://www.phpied.com/x-webkit-speech-input-and-textareas/

Here are some other JS libraries ***specifically*** built for speech recognition.

http://jqueryhouse.com/5-voice-control-javascript-libraries-for-developers/

Answer (score 1):

I used the Speech Recognition API once and used [Annyang](https://www.talater.com/annyang/).

> annyang is a tiny javascript library that lets your visitors control
>   your site with voice commands. annyang supports multiple languages,
>   has no dependencies, weighs just 3kb and is free to use.

It's as simple as:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/2.0.0/annyang.min.js"></script>

<script>
if (annyang) {

  // set your commands here, as many as you need
  var commands = {
    'play mp3': function() {
        // change this to your own play MP3 method
        audioElement.play();
    },
    'put the kettle on': function() {
        console.log("You wish!");
    }
  };

  // add commands
  annyang.addCommands(commands);

  // start listening
  annyang.start();

}
</script>
```

Annyang is a library to make the setup of voice commands easy. However, it's not the quickest solution in the world, as I *think* (people with knowledge please chip in here) the library just calls and external service (Google, I think) and has to wait for response before running your code. It's only a second or two, but it's there.

The Speech Recognition API also requires permission to use user's the microphone. When the page loads, a little popup will appear automagically and asking permission. If a user chooses 'no', your speech feature won't work.

As I said earlier, browser support is looking rather dim, still. At the time of writing this, only Chrome, Chrome for Android and Opera can use it: caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition

It's a hell of a lot of fun playing with speech, so have a play regardless of your decison to use it or not. I used it alongside [ResponsiveVoice](http://responsivevoice.org/) to speak back to me. I built a little page that sits on my desktop and I can ask her things like "What is the weather?" and she reads my local weather report to me. I ask "What's the latest?" and she reads 10 news items from my local news agency's RSS feed. I also turned it into a speech calculator. So, yeah, have a play - one day it could be widely supported.

Read more here:

- https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API?hl=en
- http://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/introducing-web-speech-api/